# How to manipulate html loaded with jQuery.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have:

```
        $.ajax({ type: 'POST',   
             url: myLink,   
             async: false,
             dataType: 'html',
             success : function(page) {

                 var fragment = page.find('#myId').html();
                                 ...

                                 // I'll append my fragment to #somewhere


        });
```

this is not working, console says `page.find is not a function`.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
var fragment = $(page).find('#myId').html();
```

`page` itself is just a string containing the html you requested...  So you have to first create a jQuery object to call jQuery methods on.